# Selenium RC - t.replace is not a function

Tags: testing, selenium

[edit for godman] I am working on a web based application, written in PHP. I am using Selenium RC to run tests on the webpages produced by this application, through a browser.

I just upgraded to Firefox 14, so I had to upgrade to Selenium RC 2.25.0.

Now I'm seeing this error when running a test with htmlSuite:

> Command execution failure. Please search the user group at
>   https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/selenium-users for error
>   details from the log window.  The error message is: t.replace is not a
>   function

The command executed is:

```
clickAndWait    //a[text()='! selenium test customer']
```

As you can see, it's not doing anything too tricky - just clicking a link. The test runs fine in the IDE, it's just when run via RC that it's a problem.

Searching in the groups revealed only really old threads dating back to version 1 of selenium.
Any ideas anyone?

[edit] I've been running the test that has these problems several times a day for the last week - and it doesn't seem to fail like this every time. This looks like it's a random problem. Has anyone seen this happen before?

[edit after the bounty got me no answers] Another example of it failing is with:

```
clickAndWait   css=a.edit_company
```

This same call works fine earlier in the same test, on the same page.

[edit] Now I'm seeing the same error with a completely separate command:

```
type    id=Address1     Address1
```

Does anyone have any suggestions about this? Any way I can even debug what's going on (I don't see this in the IDE at all)

Comment: I downgraded to 2.24.1, and am still getting the same thing, but on a different command.

Comment: I've downgraded further - all the way to 2.23.0 - still the same

Comment: Did you try it in other browsers like chrome?

Comment: Yes, I tried in Chrome - same deal. IE has never worked with selenium for me - keeps getting security errors so I can't try that.

Answer (score 0):

I am not terribly familiar with clickAndWait.  I personally prefer clicking and then doing my own custom waiting.

Try just clicking and add a Thread.Sleep(5000), or something similar, and see if the error is a result of the click or the wait part.

If it is the wait part, then I have a different suggestion than if it is the click part.

Comment: Thanks. I gave it a try - unfortunately I got the same error with "click" too.

Comment: weird.  Try using sendKeys on the element as an experiment.  It is something like:  WebElement.sendKeys(Keys.RETURN);  Oops, wait if you are using RC, then I think it is more like: typeKeys(java.lang.String locator, java.lang.String value).  Plus, I think there is a doclick method.  I know these might not be changes you want to permanently make, but the key might be in the differences.

Comment: sorry for leaving it so long, I just tried adding a typeKeys call to type the letter A on the element before the clickAndWait...and it worked without error. So instead, another test, in another suite running *before* that one fails with the same error. Weird, huh?

Comment: Scratch that - now the same test is failing, with a similar clickAndWait call, later in the test. I think this *must* be a selenium bug.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen similar issues across various platforms. It has always been somewhat random for me, so I don't use clickandWait. Generally is is much more reliable to do a plain click, and then wait for specific condition. You could do a waitforpageload, but that has also been unreliable for me so I prefer things like waitfortextpresent and waitforelementpresent.

Comment: Thanks. I gave it a try - unfortunately I got the same error with "click" too.

Answer (score -2):

Usually, this kind of error would occur if you are dealing with something that is not a string. Could you just make sure that you are dealing with strings only?

2 possibilities where it is arising from:-

1. When text() is executed -> it might be dealing with a non-string
2. a[expression] -> the expression(text() = '! selenium test customer') when evaluated to False/True might be the problem because if a is a Map/array, the corresponding key should be a string and not a bool, probably.
3. text()='! selenium test customer'  -->> is it an assignment operation? if yes,  make sure that text() returns a lvalue or a mutable object (based on the language you are using selenium rc with)

Comment: This makes no sense. Have you even used selenium?

Comment: @Hippyjim: Yes, I have used it for long with Python. As I can see that you are not satisfied with the answer, could you please add some explanation to your question. That would help some one who is reading the question to figure out the exact reason.

Comment: What part of this is not clear? please educate me. I am using SELENIUM with FIREFOX to run a test with the HTMLSUITE switch. I am using an XPATH to find an element and click it. It fails with the error shown. Your answer asks me to tell you how selenium parses the XPATH - which has nothing to do with my question.